# Не удается установить службу

Tags: windows, windows-service

Копирую в папку  `c:\Windows\System32` файл `TestService.exe`
Запускаю его там все в порядке он работает
Создаю службу, для этого использую утилиту SC

```
    sc create "AAA" binpath= C:\WINDOWS\system32\TestService.exe type= own start= auto displayname= "AAA" error= ignore
```

Служба устанавливается, но при попытке запуска пишет

> Ошибка 2: не удается найти указанный файл.

Самое интересное если мы попробуем запустить файл через `CMD` по этому пути командная строка пишет что данная программа не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ для 64 битной Windows надо использовать такой код

```
sc create "AAA" binpath= C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\TestService.exe type= own start= auto displayname= "AAA" error= ignore
```

И тогда все работает